# I don't understand why this question was put on hold. Should I even ask here?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-hold

This question:

[Is it possible to have a loop which has zero execution time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26771692/loop-with-a-zero-execution-time/26771708)

was put on hold as too broad.

Question #1: The answer is quite short, and I don't see that there are many other possible answers. So can someone explain the question hold?

Question #2: Should I even be asking this question on Meta Stack Overflow?

Comment: This is known as new user anamoly(no documentation,you have to just feel it.. :/)

Comment: Yes, this is the place to discuss stuff about SO.  I also VTC again.  There isn't a problem here, it's just chitchat.

Comment: Moot point - it's been re-opened.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I upvoted and voted to reopen.

Questions dealing with "Is it possible" are usually too broad, and a quick glance at this question might give that impression, but after reading through the entire question it seems precise and can be - and was - answered concisely.

As for your second question, it absolutely fits on Meta SO. You're seeking to gain knowledge about close voting reasons and ask a concise, clear question related to an issue.

Answer (score -1):

Yours is a reasonable interpretation, but it is by far not the only possible one -- the question is very vague, on the verge of being ill-defined.  I agree with the "too broad" close status.

You were right to ask for clarification here ... but asking two questions in one isn't entirely good form. /-;

Comment: Could you give another interpretation - I'm just not seeing one.  Thanks.

Comment: Your answer obviously hinges on the assumption that compiler optimizations are within scope of the question.  It's not at all clear from the question, and in fact, I would suppose that if the OP was aware of the issue, he was getting at the other interpretation.  But there really is no way to tell, which is one of the reasons it is too broad.

Comment: I understand now that the lack of clarity in the question can lead to different assumptions.  Thanks.

Comment: His second question was trivial. I'd be more annoyed if he asked two different questions when they're related and one is absolutely trivial to answer. I think his Meta question is entirely in good form.